# remote roslaunch searching local PC for launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to run a remote launch file running on an embedded board. My PC runs indigo and the board runs kinetic. The launch file in my PC is

```
<launch>
<machine name = "tegra-ubuntu" address="tx1" user="ubuntu" password="ubuntu" env-loader="/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/setup.sh" default="true"/>
<include file="$(find xsens_driver)/launch/xsens_driver.launch" machine="tegra-ubuntu"/>
<node machine="tegra-ubuntu" type="mtnode.py" pkg="xsens_driver" name="xsens_driver" output="screen"/>
<node machine="tegra-ubuntu" type="odom_listener_node" pkg="ego_motion" name="ego_motion_node" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

However, when I do a roslaunch, the launch fails by saying ResourceNotFound. Even though I mentioned the machine to find the launch file, the search seems to happen in the local system. If I give the complete path of the launch file like
this

```
<include file="/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/xsens_driver/launch/xsens_driver.launch" machine="tegra-ubuntu"/>
```

I get the error

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I am pretty sure that my file paths are correct. Remote nodes doesn't have any issue with execution.

What could possibly be a reason for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250591/remote-roslaunch-searching-local-pc-for-launch-file/) by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The workaround I did finally was to run the launch file from a shell script in the embedded platform. I wrote the roslaunch command on a shell script and placed it in the package folder. Then called the shell script like a node from the remote PC launch file.

```
<node machine="tegra" type=run_launch.sh pkg=ros_package_name name=run_launch output="screen"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) with karma: 76 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0